# Extract the different components of variance in a linear mixed model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, partitioning

Consider a mixed model as follows.

```
library(lme4)
# Load data
data <- structure(list(blk = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3L),
                       gent = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 10L),
                       yld = c(83, 77, 78, 78, 70, 75, 74, 79, 81, 81, 91, 79, 78, 92, 79, 87, 81, 96, 89, 82L),
                       syld = c(250, 240, 268, 287, 226, 395, 450, 260, 220, 237, 227, 281, 311, 258, 224, 238, 278, 347, 300, 289L)),
                  .Names = c("blk", "gent", "yld", "syld"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
data$blk <- as.factor(data$blk)
data$gent <- as.factor(data$gent)
```

The data is unbalanced.

```
# Mixed effect model
frmla <- "syld ~ 1 + gent + (1|blk)"
library(lme4)
model <- lmer(formula(frmla), data = data)

model
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: syld ~ 1 + gent + (1 | blk)
   Data: data
REML criterion at convergence: 73.9572
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 blk      (Intercept)  9.385  
 Residual             16.919  
Number of obs: 20, groups:  blk, 3
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)        gent2        gent3        gent4        gent5        gent6        gent7        gent8        gent9  
    256.000      -28.000       -8.333        8.000       32.127       43.678      -36.805       90.678       62.127  
     gent10       gent11       gent12  
     32.678      132.195      187.195
```

Primarily I want to compare the `gent` levels by LS means.

```
library("lmerTest")
lsmeans(model)
Least Squares Means table:
         gent Estimate Standard Error   DF t-value Lower CI Upper CI p-value    
gent  1   1.0    256.0           11.2  6.9    22.9      229      283  <2e-16 ***
gent  2   5.0    228.0           11.2  6.9    20.4      201      255  <2e-16 ***
gent  3   6.0    247.7           11.2  6.9    22.2      221      274  <2e-16 ***
gent  4   7.0    264.0           11.2  6.9    23.6      237      291  <2e-16 ***
gent  5   8.0    288.1           18.5  8.0    15.6      245      331  <2e-16 ***
gent  6   9.0    299.7           18.5  8.0    16.2      257      342  <2e-16 ***
gent  7  10.0    219.2           18.5  8.0    11.8      177      262  <2e-16 ***
gent  8  11.0    346.7           18.5  8.0    18.8      304      389  <2e-16 ***
gent  9  12.0    318.1           18.5  8.0    17.2      275      361  <2e-16 ***
gent  10  2.0    288.7           18.5  8.0    15.6      246      331  <2e-16 ***
gent  11  3.0    388.2           18.5  8.0    21.0      346      431  <2e-16 ***
gent  12  4.0    443.2           18.5  8.0    24.0      401      486  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In addition I am interested in variance partitioning.

The variance component due to random effect and residual can be estimated as follows.

```
VCrandom <- VarCorr(model)
print(VCrandom, comp = "Variance")
 Groups   Name        Variance
 blk      (Intercept)  88.083 
 Residual             286.250
```

How to partition the total variance into components due to each of the factors `gent` and `blk` along with the residual ? Something similar to the output given by `PROC MIXED` of `SAS`, where MSE is computed even when estimation is by ML or REML instead of least squares.

Should I treat the fixed effect as random just for the purpouse of getting variance component ?

```
frmla2 <- "syld ~ 1 + (1|gent) + (1|blk)"
model2 <- lmer(formula(frmla2), data = data)
model2

VCrandom2 <- VarCorr(model2)
print(VCrandom2, comp = "Variance")
 Groups   Name        Variance
 gent     (Intercept) 4152.08 
 blk      (Intercept)  116.11 
 Residual              274.92
```

If there is no random effect, variance components can be estimated using the least squares approach (ANOVA, Sum of squares, MSE).

The package `mixlm` has provision for variance partitioning using SS in case of mixed models.

```
library(mixlm)

mixlm <- lm(syld ~ 1 + r(gent) + r(blk), data)

Anova(mixlm, type="III")

Analysis of variance (unrestricted model)
Response: syld
          Mean Sq   Sum Sq Df F value Pr(>F)
gent      5360.49 58965.36 11   18.73 0.0009
blk        638.58  1277.17  2    2.23 0.1886
Residuals  286.25  1717.50  6       -      -

            Err.term(s) Err.df VC(SS)
1 gent              (3)      6 3044.5
2 blk               (3)      6   52.8
3 Residuals           -      -  286.3
(VC = variance component)

               Expected mean squares
gent      (3) + 1.66666666666667 (1)
blk       (3) + 6.66666666666667 (2)
Residuals (3)                       

WARNING: Unbalanced data may lead to poor estimates
```

The estimates are different

```
# Total variance
var(data$syld)

|source   |  model1|  model2|  mixlm|
|:--------|-------:|-------:|------:|
|gent     |      NA| 4152.08| 3044.5|
|blk      |  88.083|  116.11|   52.8|
|Residual | 286.250|  274.92|  286.3|
```

Can fixed effect variance be extracted using `predict` function as suggested here [In R: How to extract the different components of variance in a linear mixed model!](https://sites.google.com/site/alexandrecourtiol/what-did-i-learn-today/inrhowtoextractthedifferentcomponentsofvarianceinalinearmixedmodel) ?

```
var(predict(model))
```

Which is the most appropriate method compatible with `(RE)ML` estimates in lme4 ?

Comment: The [performance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/performance/performance.pdf) package in R  can measure "conditional R2" (random & fixed effects together), "marginal R2" (random effect alone), adjusted ICC (fixed effect alone) & "conditional ICC" (fixed effect controlling by random effect).
The theory behind it is in this paper:
Nakagawa, S., Johnson, P. C., & Schielzeth, H. (2017). The coefficient of determination R 2 and intra-class correlation coefficient from generalized linear mixed-effects models revisited and expanded. Journal of the Royal Society Interface, 14(134), 2017021

Answer (score 5):

This isn't exactly an answer, but whenever I see a question about "explained variance" in mixed models, I always think of this email from Douglas Bates, the original author of `lme4` and co-author of `nlme`, on the R-Sig-ME mailing list on Feb 26, 2010, in response to:

> I have written some code to implement Gelman & Pardoe's Rsq for an lmer object. It gives some believable results, but it's difficult to be confident because of the translation from Bayesian into frequentist paradigms.
>
> If anyone is interested then I'd be really happy to discuss this off-list and share/develop the code.

I think it is useful to have this email here on CV. This is Bates' reply:

> Assuming that one wants to define an R^2 measure, I think an argument
>   could be made for treating the penalized residual sum of squares from
>   a linear mixed model in the same way that we consider the residual sum
>   of squares from a linear model.  Or one could use just the residual
>   sum of squares without the penalty or the minimum residual sum of
>   squares obtainable from a given set of terms, which corresponds to an
>   infinite precision matrix.  I don't know, really.  It depends on what
>   you are trying to characterize.
>
> In other words, what's the purpose?  What aspect of the R^2 for a
>   linear model are you trying to generalize?
>
> I'm sorry if I sound argumentative but discussions like this sometimes
>   frustrate me.  A linear mixed model does not behave exactly like a
>   linear model without random effects so a measure that may be
>   appropriate for the linear model does not necessarily generalize.  I'm
>   not saying that this is the case but if the request is "I don't care
>   what the number means or if indeed it means anything at all, just give
>   me a number I can report", that's not the style of statistics I
>   practice.
>
> I regard Bill Venables' wonderful unpublished paper "Exegeses on
>   Linear Models" (just put the name in a search engine to find a copy -
>   there is only one paper with "Exegeses" and "Linear Models" in the
>   title) as required reading for statisticians.  As Bill emphasizes in
>   that paper, statistics is not just a collection of formulas (many of
>   which are based on approximations).  It's about models and comparing
>   how well different models fit the observed data.  If we start with a
>   formula and only ask ourselves "How do we generalize this formula?"
>   we're missing the point.  We should start at the model.
>
> In a linear model the R^2 statistic is a dimensionless comparison of
>   the quality of the current model fit, as measured by the residual sum
>   of squares, to the fit one would obtain from a trivial model.  When
>   the current model can be shown to contain a model with an intercept
>   term only (and whose coefficient will be estimated by the mean
>   response) then that model fit is the trivial model.  Otherwise the
>   trivial model is a prediction of zero for each response.  We know that
>   the trivial model will produce a greater residual sum of squares than
>   the current model fit because the models are nested.  The R^2 is the
>   proportion of variability not accounted for by the trivial model but
>   accounted for by the current model (my apologies to my grammar
>   teachers for having juxtaposed prepositions).
>
> The interesting point there is that when you think of the
>   relationships between models you can determine how you handle the case
>   of a model that does not have an intercept term.  If you start from
>   the formula instead you can end up calculating a negative R^2 because
>   you compare models that are not nested.  Such nonsensical results are
>   often reported.  (I think it was the Mathematica documentation that
>   gave a careful explanation of why you get a negative R^2 instead of
>   recognizing that the formula they were using did not apply in certain
>   cases.)
>
> It may be that there is a sensible measure of the quality of fit from
>   a linear mixed model that generalizes the R^2 from a linear model.  I
>   don't see an obvious candidate but I will freely admit that I haven't
>   thought much about the problem.  I would ask others who are thinking
>   about this to consider both the "what" and the "why".  George
>   Mallory's justification of "because it's there" for attempting to
>   climb Everest is perhaps a good justification for such endeavors
>   (Mallory may have questioned his rationale as he lay freezing to death
>   on the mountain).  I don't think it is a good justification for
>   manipulating formulas.